# Java Calendar.add gives wrong year

Tags: java, calendar

My program takes the current date and then, in a loop, adds a week to that date and prints out the new date. Something like:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
for (int i=0; i < 52; i++) {
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
// print date out
}
```

The add method works the way I expect it to until it reaches Dec 30, at which point the year jumps from 2012 to 2013.

so, using today's date of 4/16/2012, i tested a few different inputs:

```
this - cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 38*7);
yields- "date:1/7/2013"
this - cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 37*7);
yields- "date:12/31/2013"
this - cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 37*7-1);
yields- "date:12/30/2013"
this - cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 37*7-2);
yields- "date:12/29/2012"
```

so i notice that the year is correct up until dec 30 and dec 31, and then it corrects itself again when it gets back to january. is there a reason why it does this? does it have anything to do with 2012 being a leap year or am i misunderstanding the add method

Comment: What does the `getInstance()` method do?

Comment: No, something else wrong. For me, `cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 37 * 7)` results in `Mon Dec 31 22:29:04 SAST 2012`

Comment: No repro on OpenJDK 6 in North American Locale.  What is your JDK?  Locale?  Also, what is the actual code you're using to print out the date?

Comment: Works for me without the behavior you're describing. I'm using Java SE runtime build 1.7.0_03-b05.

Comment: `cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 37*7-1);` is correctly returning `Sun Dec 30 16:39:38 EST 2012` for me.

Comment: Not reproducible with Polish Locale, can you post complete portable [SSCCE](http://homepage1.nifty.com/algafield/sscce.html), preferably unit test?

Comment: north america too. guess it's just mine then. thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Year end date (java jautil date ) converted to string as wrong date [duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50618975/year-end-date-java-jautil-date-converted-to-string-as-wrong-date)

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 6):

Did you use `SimpleDateFormat` to print the date and use `YYYY` to produce the year? If so, that is where the problem lies. Because `YYYY` produces the week-year and not the calendar year. And as 30/12/2012 is in calendar week 1 of 2013, `YYYY` produces 2013. To get the calendar year, use `yyyy` in your `SimpleDateFormat` format string.

See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8194625

Comment: Oops silly me. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html Funny how lots of people are having this problem at the same time many years apart.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use modern java.time classes, never the terrible legacy classes such as `Calendar`.

```
LocalDate                      // Represent a date-only value with `LocalDate`, without time-of-day and without time zone.
.now(                          // Capture the current date.
    ZoneId.systemDefault()     // Specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly.
)                              // Returns a `LocalDate` object.
.plusWeeks( 1 )                // Add a week, producing a new `LocalDate` object with values based on the original, per the immutable objects pattern.
.toString()                    // Generate text representing this date value in standard ISO 8601 format of YYYY-MM-DD.
```

> 2019-01-23

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

The `Calendar` and `GregorianCalendar` classes are terrible, badly designed with flaws. Avoid them. Now replaced specifically by the `ZonedDateTime` class.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

To generate text representing that date value in standard ISO 8601 format, simply call `toString`.

```
String output = today.toString() ;
```

Date math is easy, with various `plus…` & `minus…` methods.

```
LocalDate weekLater = today.plusWeeks( 1 ) ;
```

You can also define a span of time as a `Period` or `Duration`. Then add that.

```
Period p = Period.ofWeeks( 1 ) ;
LocalDate weekLater = today.plus( p ) ;
```

## Your example

Let's test out your example dates.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2012 , Month.APRIL , 16 ) ;

Period period38Weeks = Period.ofWeeks( 38 ) ;
Period period37Weeks = Period.ofWeeks( 37 ) ;
Period period37WeeksLess1Days = period37Weeks.minusDays( 1 ) ;
Period period37WeeksLess2Days = period37Weeks.minusDays( 2 ) ;

LocalDate later_38 = ld.plus( period38Weeks ) ;
LocalDate later_37 = ld.plus( period37Weeks ) ;
LocalDate later_37_1 = ld.plus( period37WeeksLess1Days ) ;
LocalDate later_37_2 = ld.plus( period37WeeksLess2Days ) ;
```

Run [code live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/7uuMWz). No problems. The 38th week is in 2013, while week 37 dates are in 2012.

> later_38.toString(): 2013-01-07
>
> later_37.toString(): 2012-12-31
>
> later_37_1.toString(): 2012-12-30
>
> later_37_2.toString(): 2012-12-29

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7);
```

`Calendar.DATE` is same as `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH`.

Comment: Is not Calendar.DATE an equally valid answer? Reading the Calendar.add function I don't see any reason why adding DAY_OF_YEAR is any more valid than DAY_OF_MONTH (both should roll over)

Comment: yeah, i tried changing it to Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR but they seem to behave the same