# Year end date (java.util.Date) converted to string as wrong date

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date-format, date

```
String dateSt = "Sun Dec 31 10:30:00 IST 2017";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(dateSt);
DateFormat ft= new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMdd");
String dateStr = ft.format(date);
System.out.println("New Date =="+dateStr);
```

output : 20181231

it should be 20171231

need help ..

Comment: `y != Y`, check your second formatter

Comment: Also refer [MisusedWeekYear](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/MisusedWeekYear)

Comment: try `yyyyMMdd` .

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: `LocalDate.of(2017, Month.DECEMBER, 31).format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE)` gives `20171231`. Saves you the (error-prone) job of writing your own format pattern string.

Comment: If there’s any way you can, avoid relying on a three of four letter time zone abbreviation like `IST`. You cannot be sure whether Java understands it as Irish Summer Time, Israel Standard Time or India Standard Time.