# Problem: wrong output using Java Calendar class

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, simpledateformat

I am a Java developer.

I have a question about the Java `Calendar` library class.

What is my mistake? Is it a bug in Java?
Please explain to me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar cal3 = Calendar.getInstance();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");

        cal3.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);

        String today = (dateFormat.format(cal2.getTime()));

        String yesterday = (dateFormat.format(cal3.getTime()));
        System.out.println(today);
        System.out.println(yesterday);
}
```

Output:

```
01/01/2019
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
31/12/2019
```

2019 is as expected in the first line, but I had expected 2018 in the last line.

Comment: Not an answer, but now might be a good time to start reading about the Java 8 API, which makes it a lot more straightforward to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks bro ... but I want like this 31/12/2018 to 01/01/2019 now all report's are wrong what should I do?

Comment: Could you add to your question *specific* description of problem you are seeing so others with similar problem could find this question along with the possible answers (since that is main goal of this site)? "error in java calendar library" isn't really specific since it could be compilation error, runtime exception, or many others. Try to add more details about what you expected to get and what you got instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Year end date (java jautil date ) converted to string as wrong date [duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50618975/year-end-date-java-jautil-date-converted-to-string-as-wrong-date)

Answer (score 4):

Use `yyyy`(Year) for year instead `YYYY`(Week year). See the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: ohk thank's it's working